# Styling best practices for single pages/templates

Tags: php, css, page-template, wp-enqueue-style

What's the best practice for CSS that is specific to one PHP file?

For example, let's say I make a page `page-456.php` that is styled differently from the rest of the site, what's the best practice to style it and keep my HTML/text ratio good?

I did have a look and a few solutions came up - enqueuing etc. but I'm not sure if that's designed for use with templates only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Page Templates & CSS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17302/multiple-page-templates-css)

Comment: can you rephrase your question so that it's less of a discussion topic and instead an explicit question? This isn't a discussion forum and you need to be able to mark an answer not as the best practice answer, but as the _correct_ answer for all users, not just the most useful advice. If your question isn't phrased in a way that it can have a concrete answer written for it then it might be closed as offtopic/subjective/broad

Comment: I would just add a `<style>` block in your `page-456.php` file.

Comment: This is what I would normally do, but I think it's affecting my html/text ratio - do you know if there's a way around that?